# "sorry, I can't take payments in your region" message when testing Actions on Google transaction API in the UK

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I am located in London, UK and I am playing around with the Transactions API for Actions on Google using sample code found in this [repo](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-transactions-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)

However, when I run the sample I get the following message "sorry, I can't take payments in your region"

Do I need to enable test mode or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Actions on Google Transactions APIs are only currently available in the United States.

https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies

"Currently, the Transactions API is only available in the United States; apps in other countries cannot implement the API or complete transactions until the API is available there."

Comment: Any way I can bypass this? I only want to make a demo, not go to production :)

Comment: @Chris Did you find a way to make a demo?

Comment: @MrCyberthrone yes, I just created  some custom UI that looked like the payment UI and pretended I was asking payments and retrieving the address

Comment: There was a Change in Log Policies:

11/6/2018 - Moved lists of supported countries for Transactions to the corresponding guides.

You can see the updated country list in here: 
https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay