# "Sorry, I can't take payments in your region" message when testing Actions on Google Transaction API in The Netherlands

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-pay

I am located in Groningen, The Netherlands, and I'm implementing the Transactions API for Actions on Google.

Since the end of may Google returned the message "Sorry, I can't take payments in your region." I used the [sample code](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) provided by Google. Before the end of may I got another error during authentication, but that was likely due to problems with the creditcard. Unfortunately, since the end of may I was not able to get that far into the order process anymore.

This thread has some similarities with the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589077/sorry-i-cant-take-payments-in-your-region-message-when-testing-actions-on-go), but is not fully representative as it was created in 2017 when there was no support for countries besides America.

*What I tried to make it work*

1. [Google Pay](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay). The docs were updated at the end of may stating Google is working with a limited number of partners that can get access to the production Google Pay API. Besides that, the docs are not visible anymore without a direct link. They also state you can use the sandbox mode for development, even if you are not a partner. When I tried implementing the code (see sample code) the error was thrown, even though Actions that sell physical goods are supported in The Netherlands, according to the docs.
2. [Merchant-managed payment](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-custom). This was implemented using the sample code. No Oauth 2.0 was used, because there is no account to synchronize with. The same error was thrown "Sorry I can't take payments in your region." Just like the Google Pay doc, it states that The Netherlands is supported.
3. The methods above were both executed when the location in the simulator was set to Groningen.
4. The methods above were both tested in sandbox mode.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The list of available regions is here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-custom

Comment: Thanks for your response @NickFelker . It states the Netherlands is also one of the available regions. Unfortunately when I try to do transactions it says the region is not supported. I'm doing this from The Netherlands as I live there, so it is rather weird it is not working when the docs state it should...

Comment: Is this issue only occurring in the simulator?

Comment: No @NickFelker , unfortunately this issue is also occurring on an iPhone when using the Google Assistant app.

Comment: I took a look at the stackdriver logs and it states the following: `{\n \"regionCode\": \"NL\",\n}`. This means the problem must have something to do with the Orders API v3. I am not the only one having this problem as another person responded to this issue on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/gokq5x/google_pay_i_can_not_accept_payments_in_your/